# Nested resources on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, nested

My *routes.rb* file is like this:

```
  resources :campi do
    resources :unities do
      resources :buildings do
        resources :networks
      end
    end
  end
```

As you can see, I have  networks inside a building, buildings inside a unity and unities inside a campus.
However, if I have, for example:

Campus ID : 10
Unity ID: 20
Building ID: 30
Network ID: 40

My URL will be:
    **/campi/10/unities/20/buildings/30/networks/40**

I want it to be like:
    **/10/20/30/40**

How should I proceed?

And yes, my models are all correct, using has_many in an adequate way.

**EDIT:**
I want it to work like this:

If I acesse, for example, **/10/20/buildings**, I will acess the collection of buildings inside unity 20. It includes the pages for crud methods.

Comment: how you plan use `collection` routes and action like `index`, `new` with this  `/10/20/30/40` routes path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the last section in [Rails routing from the outside in](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources):

> Deeply-nested resources quickly become cumbersome. In this case, for
>   example, the application would recognize paths such as:

```
 /publishers/1/magazines/2/photos/3
```

> The corresponding route helper would be publisher_magazine_photo_url,
>   requiring you to specify objects at all three levels. Indeed, this
>   situation is confusing enough that a popular [article](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/5/nesting-resources) by Jamis Buck
>   proposes a rule of thumb for good Rails design:
>
> Resources should never be nested more than 1 level deep.

I'd suggest you to figure out a way to avoid such situation. However, if you can't avoid this arrangement then you'll have to define a named route to solve the situation:

```
get '/:campi_id/:unity_id/:building_id/:network_id', to: 'networks#show',   as: :network
get '/:campi_id/:unity_id/buildings',                to: 'buildings#index', as: :buildings
```

I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Since my original purpose for the website I'm developing is just LEARNING rails,I think I can assign each of the paths manually.
However, from now on, I will try not to nest resources do deeply, as in this case. Thank you for your answer.